# Display WordPress Custom post by Meta Data

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, args, meta-key

I am trying to display my custom posts by date order from my meta_key in wordpress.

It is a custom post for events happening and I need to display them in order of 'upcoming event'

My code so far is:

```
$today = date('d/m/y');
$args = array( 
                   'post' => 'ID', 
                   'post_type' => 'foodswaps', 
                   'posts_per_page' => 3, 
                   'meta_key' => '00.event-date',
                   'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 
                   'order' => 'ASC',
                   'meta_value_num' => $today,
                   'meta_compare' => '>='
            );
```

The results do post in order but only of day. So they are appearing in this order of:
27/11/13

28/12/13

29/11/13

The order should post in:
27/11/13

29/11/13

28/12/13

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE:
Explaining the Meta Key:

The meta_keys I have are:

Name of Field  |    Value

00.event-date   |   28/11/13  ie d/m/y

01.app-key       |  122334455669

02.user-key | xjsk284k38dj

etc.

They have 00, 01, 02, etc so they appear in alphanumeric order as there are a number of fields to display the the users needs to fill in. They list in a specific ored to make it more useable.

Comment: I have also tried meta_value instead of meta_value_num

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is your solution

```
   $args = array(
         'showposts' => 5, // optional up to you
         'post_type' => 'foodswaps',
         'meta_key' => '00.event-date', // must use correctly, I am little confused why your meta key name like that start with 00, however.
         'orderby' => 'meta_value',
         'meta_query' => array(
               array(
                    'key' => '00.event-date',
                    'value' => date("Y-m-d"),                            
                    'compare' => '>='
                    )
                )
   );
```

Fill the meta key value Y-m-d i.e. 2013-11-27

Comment: Sadly that didn't work, all it did was reverse the output

My meta keys are listed in a certain order of pre-defined meta keys for users to follow, so the next one is 01.api-key, 02.user-key etc.

Comment: Please let me know your issue clearly. what is `01.api-key, 02.user-key`

Comment: you were asked that put the date as Y-m-d i.e. 2013-11-27